# How can ı build Tab Bar with 20 tab without typing 20 times Tab?

Tags: flutter

I have a tabbar and ıt's has 20 tabs. I typed 20 time tab but this isn't a smart way.

What is the best practice to do this?

```
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[0]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[1]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[2]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[3]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[4]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[5]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[6]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[7]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[8]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[9]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[10]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[11]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[12]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[13]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[14]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[15]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[16]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[17]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[18]),
      Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryNames[19]),
```

Comment: Why you don`t loop that.

Comment: `tabs: [for (var i=0; i<20; i++) Tab(text: CategoryNames.categoryName[i])]`

Comment: @shohruhMaxmudov    Of course I tried looping and even wrote a function for it but ı get an eror. Now ı just added this loop and it's worked. Something must have gone wrong the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the map function on the list : CategoryNames.categoryNames to map every String element of this list to a Widget

```
CategoryNames.categoryNames.map<Widget>((String element) => Tab(text: element,));
```

this map function will return a new List of widgets : List<Widget>

the previous map function returns an Iterable as noted by @pskink so to covert it to a List use toList() function on the Iterable

```
CategoryNames.categoryNames.map<Widget>((String element) => Tab(text: element,)).toList();
```

Comment: @pskink it can be converted to a list using `.toList()` on the `Iterable`

Comment: I assign it to a variable with this code in InitState. I think this is the most logical way for now. Thank you.